# Getting 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getiterator' error when run createMosaicGDAL.run

Tags: python, modis, mosaic, pymodis

I am using pyModis to mosaic some tiles of MCD12Q1. I have downloaded the dataset and I am trying to mosaic those tiles.

```
from pymodis.convertmodis_gdal import createMosaicGDAL

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dest, '*.hdf'))
subset = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

output_hdf = os.path.join(dest, 'MCD12Q21_mosaic.hdf')
print(output_hdf)

mosaic = createMosaicGDAL(files, subset, 'HDF4Image')

mosaic.run(output_hdf)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <module>
----> 1 mosaic.run(output_hdf)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/pymodis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymodis/convertmodis_gdal.py:613, in createMosaicGDAL.run(self, output, quiet)
    611         n.copy_into(t_fh, 1, i, fill)
    612     i = i + 1
--> 613 self.write_mosaic_xml(output)
    614 t_fh = None
    615 if not quiet:

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/pymodis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymodis/convertmodis_gdal.py:585, in createMosaicGDAL.write_mosaic_xml(self, prefix)
    583     listHDF.append(os.path.realpath(i.strip()))
    584 pmm = parseModisMulti(listHDF)
--> 585 pmm.writexml("%s.xml" % prefix)

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/pymodis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymodis/parsemodis.py:957, in parseModisMulti.writexml(self, outputname, pretty)
    955 # add CollectionMetaData
    956 cmd = self.ElementTree.SubElement(gurmd, 'CollectionMetaData')
--> 957 self.valCollectionMetaData(cmd)
    958 # add DataFiles
    959 df = self.ElementTree.SubElement(gurmd, 'DataFiles')

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/pymodis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymodis/parsemodis.py:760, in parseModisMulti.valCollectionMetaData(self, obj)
    758 values = []
    759 for i in self.parModis:
--> 760     values.append(i.retCollectionMetaData())
    761 self._cicle_values(obj, self._checkvaldict(values))

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/pymodis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymodis/parsemodis.py:138, in parseModis.retCollectionMetaData(self)
    136 self.getGranule()
    137 collect = dict()
--> 138 for i in self.granule.find('CollectionMetaData').getiterator():
    139     if i.text.strip() != '':
    140         collect[i.tag] = i.text

AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getiterator'
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this was [fixed](https://github.com/lucadelu/pyModis/pull/138) but not released, try installing from Git:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/lucadelu/pyModis.git
```

Comment: Thank you, that works.